# python: read grpc proto request in interceptor

Tags: php, python, protocol-buffers, grpc

How can I read grpc proto request in interceptor with Python?

In PHP, I can read the `$argument`, it's what I need.

```
<?php

use Grpc\Interceptor;

class MyInterceptor extends Interceptor
{


    public function interceptUnaryUnary($method,
                                        $argument,
                                        $deserialize,
                                        array $metadata = [],
                                        array $options = [],
                                        $continuation)
    {
        // $argument is what I needto 
        return parent::interceptUnaryUnary($method, $argument, $deserialize, $metadata, $options, $continuation);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, gRPC Python doesn't have a complete server interceptor implemenataion that allow you to access `request` or `servicer_context`, but you may access to `method` string and `invocation_metadata`, for more detail check the [history](https://github.com/grpc/proposal/blob/master/L13-python-interceptors.md). If the semantic you want to achieve can be implemented in Python's metaclass or inheritance, please do so. If you would like to request for this feature, please post an issue in the GitHub repo [grpc/grpc](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues)...

Here are some resources that might help you find the answer:

- [The documentation for Python interceptors](https://grpc.io/grpc/python/grpc.html#service-side-interceptor)
- [The design of Python interceptors](https://github.com/grpc/proposal/blob/master/L13-python-interceptors.md)
- [The example for Python interceptors](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/tree/master/examples/python/interceptors/headers)
- [The example Python interceptor for server](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/examples/python/interceptors/headers/request_header_validator_interceptor.py)

Comment: Has anything changed after 5 years? I need such interceptor too :)

Answer (score 1):

I implemented a small [grpc-interceptor](https://pypi.org/project/grpc-interceptor/) package which provides a server interceptor that has access to the request and context. It uses the built in `grpc.ServerInterceptor`, and just simplifies the interface.

Here's a short snippet for how to use it:

```py
class MyInterceptor(ServerInterceptor):
    def intercept(self, method, request, context, method_name):
        # Do fancy stuff here...
        return method(request, context)
```

There are more complete examples in the [documentation](https://grpc-interceptor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

It has an MIT license, so you're free to use it however you like. If you'd rather not use the package, but want to see how it works, the code is [here](https://github.com/d5h-foss/grpc-interceptor/blob/ad5857d584cfa012f3b4c5b17b5f1cd3a5ade8bd/src/grpc_interceptor/server.py#L9). It was adapted and simplified from an [OpenTracing PR](https://github.com/opentracing-contrib/python-grpc/pull/14/files#diff-f582f610062878a77db815e9d5a17430R16).